# Integration testing with .NET 6, EF Core 6, and xUnit

Tags: integration-testing, .net-6.0, xunit.net, ef-core-6.0

Has anyone had any success in setting up integration testing for web applications written in .NET 6 and EntityFramework Core 6, and using SQLite in-memory database? I am having issues with test setup/teardown, so tests which run fine in isolation, start randomly failing when running all tests together.

My test context is set up based on the Microsoft examples:

```
public class TestApplication : AutofacWebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = FakeJwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = FakeJwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddFakeJwtBearer();

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .AddAuthenticationSchemes(FakeJwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
            });

            var connectionString = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder($"DataSource=file:{Guid.NewGuid()}?cache=shared&mode=memory");
            var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString.ToString());
            connection.Open();

            var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext>));
            if (descriptor != null)
            {
                services.Remove(descriptor);
            }

            services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlite(connection);
            });

            var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            using var scope = sp.CreateScope();
            var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
            var db = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
            var logger = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<TestApplication>>();

            db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            db.Database.EnsureCreated();

            try
            {
                logger.LogInformation("Initialising in-memory database with test data");
                TestData.Initialise(db);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred seeding the database with test messages. Error: {Message}", ex.Message);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

which will be used in my test fixtures something like this:

```
public class WhenGettingPartners
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task ItShouldAcceptValidRequests()
    {
        await using var app = new TestApplication();
                
        var client = app.CreateClient().WithRoles(Scopes.PartnerRead);
        
        var result = await client.GetAsync("/Partners");
        result.Should().BeSuccessful();

        var data = await result.Content.ReadAsType<Partner[]>();
        data.Should().NotBeEmpty();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task ItShouldRejectUnauthorisedRequests()
    {
        await using var app = new TestApplication();
                
        var client = app.CreateClient();
        
        var result = await client.GetAsync("/Partners");
        result.Should().HaveStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }
}
```

If I select an individual test case and run it, it works fine; if I select the entire text fixture and run it, it works fine. But when I run the entire test project, then tests will fail randomly, usually when it tries to recreate the database and finds the tables already exist.

I've tried using xUnit's `IClassFixture` interface to share one instance of `TestApplication` across all tests in the fixture:

```
public abstract class ApiTestFixture : IClassFixture<TestApplication>
{
    public ApiTestFixture(TestApplication application)
    {
        App = application;
    }

    public TestApplication App { get; }
}

public class WhenGettingClients : ApiTestFixture
{
    public WhenGettingClients(TestApplication app) : base(app)
    {
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task ItShouldAcceptValidRequests()
    {
        var client = App.CreateClient().WithRoles(Scopes.ClientRead);
        
        var result = await client.GetAsync("/Clients");
        result.Should().BeSuccessful();

        var data = await result.Content.ReadAsType<Client[]>();
        data.Should().HaveCount(2);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task ItShouldRejectUnauthorisedRequests()
    {
        var client = App.CreateClient();
        
        var result = await client.GetAsync("/Clients");
        result.Should().HaveStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }
}
```

but that fails in exactly the same way.

**Update**

I am developing using the Rider IDE from JetBrains; the same issue occurs if I run the tests in Visual Studio. However, I noticed that if I test with code coverage in Rider, then the tests all pass! Similarly, if I test with profiling in Rider, then the tests all pass; so I'm wondering if there's something more esoteric going on, that the code coverage runner somehow forces the tests to execute in a manner which is more deterministic or less likely to result in test pollution.